# Showing Previous Values on page

Tags: javascript, html, css

How to show Previous Page Values in html By clicking on back button. My Problem is When i click back button it always refresh the page by going back on it

Answer (score 0):

Use `sessionStorage` to store data that needs to be persisted in a browser session:

Storing:

```
window.sessionStorage['key'] = JSON.stringify(jsonData)
```

Retrieving:

```
JSON.parse(window.sessionStorage['key'])
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to persist data in your website You can use local storage. there are two types of local storage.

1. window.localStorage
2. window.sessionStorage

**localStorage** does not remove data when the browser is closed and it has no expiration date

**sessionStorage** stores data for only one session the doesnt persist once you closed the browser tab

Samples

```
// Local Storage Sample
// to store
localStorage.setItem("count", 3);
// to retrieve
var count = localStorage.getItem("count");

//Session Storage Sample

//To Store
sessionStorage.count = 3;

//To Retrive
var count = sessionStorage.count;
```